# Combination of maximum values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, maximum, attribute-rules

I'm making classification by rules to create a map with different colors;

I have 4 values (`A,B,C,D`) assigned to some areas and I want to find the maximum values between the four in each area. Thus, I wrote this expression in the classification by rules --> `A = max(A,B,C,D)`, the same for the other three cases.

In addition, I want to evaluate when in that area the maximum values are both (for example) `A` and `B`. I want to apply this to all the possible combinations (`A-B/A-C/A-D/B-C/B-D/C-D`), how can I write these rules?

I already try:

- `A=B=max(A,B,C,D)`
- `A=max(A,B,C,D)=B=max(A,B,C,D)`
- others similar

and none of them works. What are possible solutions?

Comment: For each feature you want to determine which field out of A, B, C or D holds the highest integer value?

Comment: Maybe you could get the second highest value as a second step (as shown here https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/j04igr/how_can_i_select_the_second_highest_value_in_the/) and then compare if it is the same value or smaller that the max value.

Comment: I have an attribute table with a lot of columns. I want to determine which is the maximum number per raw for only 4 columns, more in detail the columns A,B,C,D. So, for each of these 4 columns, I want to say which number is the highest for each raw, and to do that I wrote this script A = max(A,B,C,D), for each of the variables (see this [LINK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328580/finding-maximum-distribution-between-multiple-columns)). Now, I want to know if there are more than 1 variable that reach the maximum value.

Comment: I want to put the rule in "classification by rule" like for example: "if A and B are both the maximum value then color that area in red", and this for all the combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the use case (if you want to get a list with the fieldnames containing the max or if you only want to count the number of fields), there are different solutions:

1. If you want to **get a list** of the fieldnames that contain the maximum value, use this expression:

   ```
    array_to_string(
        array_filter (
            with_variable(
                'mp',
                map('A',A,'B',B,'C',C,'D',D), -- list all field twice: first in single quotes ('), than without quotes or in double quotes (")
                array_foreach (
                    generate_series (0,3),
                    if (
                        map_avals(@mp)[@element] = array_max(map_avals(@mp)),
                        map_akeys(@mp)[@element],
                        ''
                    )
                )
            ),
            @element >0
        )
    )
   ```

   [image]
2. If you want to **count** how often the maximum value of attribute fields `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` is contained in these four fields. To do so, use this expression:

   ```
   array_count( 
       array(A,B,C,D),
       array_max(array(A,B,C,D))
   )
   ```

   *Result of the expression in column `count_max`: row one contains 4 times value 46, thus the result is 4; row 2: max. value is 38, 38 appears 3 times (A,B,D), thus the result is 3; row 3: max=49, which appears twice, result=2 etc.:*
   [image]

   *The more often the max. value appears, the darker the symbol is:*
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Babel, you solved my problem! Just a little thing, at the beginning the code didn't worked, you need to update the program at the latest version. Thanks again.
Option 1 works perfect

Answer (score 2):

There's no such max function. You can create an array of field values and then take the maximum: `array_max(array("A", "B", "C", "D"))`

To categorize the combinations of maximum values in a pair of fields, select the **Categorized** symbology option in the symbology tab in properties of the layer, and the, use the following expression as the value, click the **Classify** button. Now you'll have each different combination of fields, you can select a color for each category.

```
with_variable(
    'max_fields',
    with_variable(
        'fields',
        array('A', 'B', 'C'), -- set the fields you want to use for this classification inside single quotes and separated by comma.
        with_variable(
            'max_value',
            array_max(array_foreach(@fields, attribute(@element))),
            array_filter(
                @fields,
                attribute(@element) = @max_value
            )
        )
    ),
    if(
        array_length(@max_fields) = 2,
        array_to_string(array_sort(@max_fields), '-'),
        NULL
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Mayo, thanks for the answer. I take suggestion from this question, that solve my first problem (to find the maximum value per raw in some columns, see this [LINK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328580/finding-maximum-distribution-between-multiple-columns); now, I want to find if there are more than one value that can reach the maximum value

Comment: @Mark, and when there are more than one maximum value you will always apply the same expression (`A-B/A-C/A-D/B-C/B-D/C-D`, or it depends on what fields have the maximum value?

Comment: And @Mark, your are aware that this expression (`A-B/A-C/A-D/B-C/B-D/C-D`) will first evaluate the divisions and then the subtractions, right?

Comment: I have an attribute table with a lot of columns. I want to determine which is the maximum number per raw for only 4 columns, more in detail the columns A,B,C,D. So, for each of these 4 columns, I want to say which number is the highest for each raw, and to do that I wrote this script A = max(A,B,C,D), for each of the variables (see this [LINK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328580/finding-maximum-distribution-between-multiple-columns)). Now, I want to know if there are more than 1 variable that reach the maximum value

Comment: I want to put the rule in "classification by rule" like for example: "if A and B are both the maximum value then color that area in red", and this for all the combinations

Comment: You are wrong reading that comment in that way, it is not an "expression" it just show the combination that I want to evaluate, like: where A and B are the maximum? where A and C are the maximum? where A and D are the maximum? and so on...

Comment: @Mark, sorry I misinterpret your question, take a look at the update...